# Alternative to ffplay for Raw Video Playback without X Windows

Tags: linux, xorg, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ffmpeg

I am successfully capturing frames from a small USB IR camera on the small Raspberry Pi Linux board. I am using the 'libseek' code to do this:

```
https://github.com/zougloub/libseek
```

I can see alot of garbage being printed on the terminal when I remove the '|' symbol from the following command:

```
sudo ./build/seek-test \
 | ffplay -i - -f rawvideo -video_size 208x156 -pixel_format gray16le
```

If I startx I can see frames displayed in a window.

The problem is I don't want to have X started ( or even installed ) on the Pi. I have a small Adafruit TFT touchscreen that shows the console on /dev/fb1. I can use fbi to show images on that display.

What can I use instead of ffplay to show the raw video feed on /dev/fb1 without X? Thanks!

Comment: fbff ( repo.or.cz/fbff.git ) is probably the best tool for that. But you are probably on raspbian and they (like debian) use libav instead of classic ffmpeg libraries makes it too difficult for compiling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to do something with gstreamer, like `/build/seek-test | gst-launch-1.0 fbsrc ! videoparse width=208 height=156 format=gray16-le ! fbdevsink`. Note that I didn't test it.

Answer (score -1):

```
mplayer -vo fbdev2:/dev/fb1 -xy 320 -zoom tv:// -tv device=/dev/video0
```